# Wireless internet not working only while television near router is on

Tags: wireless-networking

Anyone have a clue why my roommates internet becomes spotty as soon as the television near the router is on? We have comcast xfinify and her room is on the far end of the house. The room right next door to hers has no problems, however, and we have no idea why.

Comment: Check for power issues, or electrical interference perhaps. What's the make and model of the TV and the make and model of the router?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the TV generates just enough RF noise to obscure the weak signal from your roommate's room at the other end of the house.

Moving the router a few meters away from the TV should resolve the problem.

Comment: You can also switch to a 5.0 GHz router less likely a TV will interfere with that frequency. TV could also be a smart TV but impossible to determine that based on information provided

Comment: @Ramhound Minor style note: It's 5 GHz, not 5.0 GHz. The lowest frequency that the lowest Wi-Fi channel in the 5 GHz band uses is 5.17 GHz. So the 5GHz Wi-Fi band doesn't go all the way down to 5.0 GHz.

Comment: You wrote the samething twice, and Wifi is 2.4 GHz and 5.0 GHz the specific frequencies within the spectrum seems to be semantics was just trying to suggest staying away from 2.4 GHz

Comment: I have come across several smart TVs now that when powered on produce an enormous amount of RF energy. Using a spectrum analyzer you can see normal amounts of RF energy while they are powered off, but then constant signal stronger than -30 dBm when powered on. This is strong enough to disrupt most wireless signals in the area. The TVs in question have all either been manufacturer defects or damaged after leaving the factory (usually the vendor's response). Unfortunately without a spectrum analyzer to establish this is the case, this is difficult to prove for the normal user.